# How "File not open a bytes-like object is required, not 'int' " could be solved?

Tags: python, http, networking

I am writing a simple http server code using socket-network-programming as a way of connection between client-server nodes.

simply, I used my browser as client and I coded server side using python.

Now, everything seems right but when I run the server plus browser with specific path 'filename',like (http//:localhost:8080/filename) the browser gets my exception statement that is:
    404 Not Found

I believe my trouble is here:
    client_socket.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n".encode())

The following error appears on server terminal console screen.

```
File not open  a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

Any help or though is appreciated.

Comment: We can't help without your code; and the complete traceback.

Comment: File header is not `string output` ! Need push string with `binary system`, `#!/usr/bin/python -u`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was very simple. All what I did after a lot of digging on the Internet is the following:
    client_socket.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n".encode())

Sincerely